# Why my Django 3.2 admin CSS is not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I am really really frustrated being failed to find the issue.
My django 3.2 admin is looking like without CSS only HTML. I am new to django. I don't know what happened.

I have collected static files(CSS, Js, etc.) into the static folder of the project by this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I also used `whitenoise` package to manage this stuff. But failed to do as a beginner.

**Django Admin Login Page**

[image]

**Django Admin**

[image]

**My project mac and other two apps blog and shop**

[image]

**Here is my settings.py of the project**

```html
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mac.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mac.wsgi.application'

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I need help please with the **3.2 version**. Any help is really really appreciated.

Comment: is this using local runserver?

Comment: @Trent   Yes. Local runserver. I mean Pycharm runserver like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code to your urls.py file so that django knows where to grab static and media files from

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.views.static import serve
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Sorry to say. That's not working. 
I applied your code with this on urls.py:
<code>
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.views.static import serve
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += [
    
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),

]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
</code>